# Wrapper methods and wrapper classes

Tags: java, wrapper

I am working on exam prep at the moment and I came across a question down the bottom of this post..It relates to Wrapper methods Vs Wrapper classes. Is there a difference here? As I understand that wrapper classes allow primitives to be wrapped in objects so they can be included in things like collections. Wrapper classes also have a bunch of utility methods to allows to convert to and from string objects. I have a question below that asks about wrapper methods and relates them to getter/setter methods. Am I right to think that the set wrapper method is just taking a primitive and wrapping it in an object or is it doing something different?

What are wrapper methods and when are they useful?

In the City class write the set/get wrapper methods that will allow direct access to each of its location's attributes, latitude and longitude., e.g., setLatitude:

```
class City {
    //...

    public void setLatitude(double value) 
    {
        location.setLat(value);
    }

    //your code:
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the getter and setter methods.

Comment: Wrapper methods is a non-standard terminology (AFAIK). It seems to me that what they're calling wrapper methods are methods which only delegate to another, wrapped object. In the above, `setLatitude()` delegates to `Location.setLat()`.

Comment: Are you talking about wrapper classes or wrapper methods ?

Comment: Basically, there's no such thing as a wrapper method. Someone, somewhere may define that term, but it's not in common use.

Comment: I pretty confident that wrapper classes are just a way to wrap primitives into objects so they can be included in things like collections. However the question I came across talks of wrapper methods and relates them to getters/setters. Maybe there is something very obvious I am missing here. Is the setter wrapping a primitive (which is a double being passed here) in an object?? Just a guess

Comment: Sorry Marko, I didn't see ur response before I posted..Many thanks for your input..It's appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper class is a class that extends the usability of a certain class or primitive. For example take this class:

```
public class NewBoolean{
    private boolean value = false;
    public NewBoolean(boolean state) {
        value = state;
    }
    public boolean value() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public boolean isTrue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isFalse() {
        return !value;
    }

    public boolean compare(boolean anotherBoolean){
       return value==anotherBoolean;
    }
}
```

It can replace any `boolean` value, and has new methods that can extend the usability of a `boolean` primitive.

A wrapper method could refer to a wrapper function.
Wrapper methods are just methods that call other methods, for example, we might have this two methods in a class:

```
public void setFullScreen() { }
public void setWindowMode() { }
```

And a wrapper method might be:

```
public void toggleFullScreen() {
    if(fullscreen) {
         setWindowMode();
    }
    else {
         setFullScreen();
    }
}
```

In short, a method that calls another method already inside the class. Another example woud be a `setResolution(w,h);` and a wrapper method what calls `setDefaultResolution()`, which would in turn call `setResolution(DEFAULT_W,DEFAULT_H)` inside.

Comment: public boolean isTrue() {return value;} public boolean isFalse() {return !value;}

Comment: nice logic and optimization there.

Comment: `public boolean compare(boolean anotherBoolean) { return value==anotherBoolean;}`. See the pattern? Each time you have `if (booleanExpression) { return true; } else { return false; }`, you should return the boolean expression directly.

Answer (score 0):

I heard the term 'wrapper class' being used as a synonym for a decorator class (see the ['decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)') which has more usages then just allowing primitive types to be inserted into a Collection