# Realm for Android: Store a non-RealmObject inside a RealmObject one

Tags: java, android, realm

Straight to the code. We have two classes:

```
class Rocket extends RealmObject
{
 @PrimaryKey
 private long id;
 private String name;
 private Payload pl;
}

class Payload
{
 private String name;
 private double mass;
}
```

How do I store a Rocket in a Realm?

1. I could manually serialize the Payload into a sort of String then save it along with the Rocket. But its slow.
2. I could extend the Payload from RealmObject and save it into table. But if I do so I should delete the Payload every time I delete the parent Rocket. Its definitely not an option as the model gets really messy and complicated.

I may implement the Serializable or Parcelable interface if it requires me to but I really need to save my object into a Realm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your main concern with the obvious solution (extending `RealmObject`) is that you'd like to delete the `Payload` when you delete the parent `Rocket`. Unfortunately, cascading deletes [are not yet supported](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1104). Your options are:

- serialize to a string (note this has to be done outside of the `Rocket` object)
- make `Payload` extend `RealmObject` and give it the same primary key as your `Rocket` objects and then delete them at the same time (via the same key)

I'd recommend the second solution, along with a method something like the following:

```
private void deleteRocket(long id) {
    realm.where(Rocket.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst().removeFromRealm();
    realm.where(Payload.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst().removeFromRealm();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I dont need to cascade delete relatives. I just need to store a structure (a class with a few member variables) inside that db object. I could implement the Serializable interface if it was needed. Cascade delete is one of a few options how to implement similar functionality via storing custom RealmObjects. But there should be a simplier way to achieve this. Im disappointed TBH. But still it's a nice DB. (Marked as accepted as I don't think there is a simplier way to do what I want.)

Comment: Ah, I see. If you [check out this answer I left earlier, and the comment from Christian Melchior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35592653/1217087) you'll see that custom getters/setters (ie `setPayload(Payload p)`, where the private member is a `String`) are currently unsupported, _but_ are coming in 0.88. So you could implement your serialize/deserialize logic there, once 0.88 is released (there's a beta snapshot available now, I believe).

Comment: beta snapshot with customized setters/getters support is not availabe for now (Feb.5 2016 1:15 am UTC). But it is coming very soon. See the status of https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2196

Comment: Thanks @beeender! I saw that there [is a 0.88-SNAPSHOT available](http://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local/io/realm/realm-android/), so I (incorrectly) assumed that this change was included in that. I'll keep an eye on that PR though :)